# Gradle build failing due to keystore.properties file missing

Tags: android, gradle, android-alarms

I'm trying to use this alarm app on Android Studio - https://github.com/philliphsu/ClockPlus . However, gradle build is failing (error message below). Please let me know what needs to be fixed for this to work.

Error:/Users/***/Documents/Apps/ClockPlus-master/keystore.properties (No such file or directory). Let me know what exactly is this keystore.properties and is it possible to create this file as it's not available in the github repo files.

Comment: `keystore.properties` file is used to build a release apk, change your build variants to debug mode

Answer (score 11):

> what exactly is this keystore.properties?

When you want to publish your app in the google play, you need to sign your app. When you create a signing configuration,Android Studio ,by default, adds your signing information in plain text to the module's build.gradle files. If you are working with a team or open-sourcing your code, you should move this sensitive information out of the build files so it is not easily accessible to others. To do this, you should create a separate properties file to store secure information and refer to that file in your build files. That file is the keystore properties file.

[Read more about this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore)

> Is it possible to create this file as it's not available in the github
>   repo files?

Create a file named keystore.properties in the root directory of your project. This file should contain your signing information, as follows:

```
    storePassword=myStorePassword
    keyPassword=mykeyPassword
    keyAlias=myKeyAlias
    storeFile=myStoreFileLocation
```

If you do not have store password, key password etc. you should sign your app.

[Read more about this](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-shared-keystore)

The whole information about this is in the Android Developer documentation, in the link I provided above.